# Syntax for nested IF statements in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to run the following SPARQL query, but it keeps returning `SR171: Transaction timed out`.

```sql
SELECT ?isBusAvailable WHERE {
  SELECT DISTINCT IF (
  (
  SELECT ?value2 WHERE {
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 ontology:value ?value2 }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 rdf:label "Availability" }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 ontology:isObservedValueOf ?obsID2}
      GRAPH data: { ?obsID2 ssn:observationResultTime ?time2 }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsID2 ssn:observedBy ?id2 }
      GRAPH meta: { ?id2 rdf:label "MyBusService" } 
  } ORDER BY DESC (?time2) LIMIT 1) > 1, "Take Bus", (
                       SELECT ?isBikeAvailable WHERE {
                       SELECT DISTINCT IF (
                       (
                       SELECT ?value3 WHERE {
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID3 ontology:value ?value3 }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID3 rdf:label "Availability" }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID3 ontology:isObservedValueOf ?obsID3}
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsID3 ssn:observationResultTime ?time3 }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsID3 ssn:observedBy ?id3 }
                            GRAPH meta: { ?id3 rdf:label "MyBikeService" } 
                       } ORDER BY DESC (?time3) LIMIT 1
                       ) > 0, "Take Bike", "Take Taxi") as ?isBikeAvailable WHERE { ?1 ?2 ?3}})) as ?isBusAvailable WHERE { ?4 ?5 ?6}}
```

If I run them individually, it runs in under 1 second. The following example works.

```sql
SELECT ?isBusAvailable WHERE {
  SELECT DISTINCT IF (
  (
  SELECT ?value2 WHERE {
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 ontology:value ?value2 }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 rdf:label "Availability" }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID2 ontology:isObservedValueOf ?obsID2}
      GRAPH data: { ?obsID2 ssn:observationResultTime ?time2 }
      GRAPH data: { ?obsID2 ssn:observedBy ?id2 }
      GRAPH meta: { ?id2 rdf:label "MyBusService" } 
  } ORDER BY DESC (?time2) LIMIT 1) > 1, "Take Bus", 'Take Bike') as ?isBusAvailable WHERE { ?4 ?5 ?6}}
```

If the result from the first query is true, return 'Take Bus'; else, run the second query, and return either 'Take Bike' or 'Take Taxi'.

Apparently the problem is with the second query (from the false condition on the first query). After "Take Bus", if I change the second query to "Take Bike", it works.

Comment: According to [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), this (regardless of how long it takes to execute) isn't a legal SPARQL query.  The same probably applies to the answer you posted.  Have you considered rephasing the query a bit?

Comment: That is correct. The syntax of the query posted in this question is incorrect. That is my question is all about. The query from the answer I posted works. Can you please let me know what do you mean by "rephasing"? Also, please improve the answer I posted.

Comment: My point was that the syntax in your answer, even if some SPARQL engine accepts it, is not legal SPARQL syntax either.  E.g., `select distinct if( ... )` isn't legal SPARQL.  By rephrase, I meant that you should consider restructuring your SPARQL query so that it's legal.  Once it's legal, we can help in making it more performant.  Also, it would help if you can tell us what the query is trying to accomplish, and what the data is like.  It *looks* like the query could be written more simply, but it's hard to say, since *we* don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I have two services: BusService and BikeService. The query is trying to retrieve the "Available" property of the bus. If a bus is available, it will return "Take Bus". If the bus is not available, check to see if there are any bikes available. If there are bikes available return "Take Bike", otherwise return "Take Taxi". Basically, I have 2 graphs. One is with the metadata (i.e., meta:) of services and the other one contains the data (i.e., data: in the example) produced by the services. It picks the id of the service from the meta and checks the last reading in the data graph.

Comment: Given the service name, and the property which I'm interested in (e.g., Availability), I want to retrieve the last reading for that service. Based on the values returned, I want to take some decisions, as described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@andrei -- I think your `?isBusAvailable` confuses matters -- given the literal values you return in the end, this might be better `?travelMethod`.

As I read things, the question here was really how to properly construct the nested `IFs` -- and the title of the question should perhaps be "What is correct syntax for nesting IF statements in SPARQL?"

In simple flow, I think what you're doing is checking for an available bus, and returning "Take bus" if such exists; if not, you check for an available bike, and return "Take bike" if that exists; if not, you return "Take taxi". In psuedo-code, `IF AVAIL bus, THEN take bus, ELSE ( IF AVAIL bike, THEN take bike, ELSE take taxi )`.

@joshua-taylor was right about one thing — `SELECT DISTINCT IF (…)` isn't strictly valid, but the fix is just an extra paren wrapper -- e.g., the following is valid (and validates) --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( IF ( ( 1 = 1 ) 
                     , "true" 
                     , "false" 
                     )           AS ?test ) 
WHERE { ?x ?y ?z } 
LIMIT 1
```

But fixing this in your query doesn't get any better output from the validator. In fact, replacing the inner `(SELECT ?value … LIMIT 1)` queries with `1` makes the whole large query validate --

```
SELECT ?travelMethod 
   WHERE 
     { 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                         ( IF 
                               (
                                  (
                                     1  > 0
                                  )
                               ,  "Take Bus"
                               ,  (
                                        IF (
                                              (
                                                 1  > 0
                                              )
                                           ,  "Take Bike"
                                           ,  "Take Taxi"
                                           )
                                  )
                               )  AS  ?travelMethod
                         ) 
        FROM         data: 
        WHERE        { ?1  ?2  ?3 }
     }
```

-- and those inner `(SELECT ?value … LIMIT 1)` queries validate on their own, too --

```
SELECT    ?value 
WHERE     
          {
             GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:value              ?value          }
             GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  rdf:label                   "Availability"  }
             GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:isObservedValueOf  ?obsID          }
             GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observationResultTime   ?time           }
             GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observedBy              ?id             }
             GRAPH meta: { ?id          rdf:label                   "MyBusService"  } 
          }  
ORDER BY  DESC (?time) 
LIMIT     1
```

I believe the following is valid syntax -- even though the sparql.org validator chokes on it -- but I can't be sure it executes because I don't have time to rejigger the query to run against a random endpoint and data set.  If you rework the query to run against, say, DBpedia, you could help the next person!

```
SELECT ?travelMethod 
   WHERE 
     { 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                         ( IF 
                               (
                                  (
                                     (  SELECT    ?value 
                                        WHERE     
                                                  {
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:value              ?value          }
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  rdf:label                   "Availability"  }
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:isObservedValueOf  ?obsID          }
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observationResultTime   ?time           }
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observedBy              ?id             }
                                                     GRAPH meta: { ?id          rdf:label                   "MyBusService"  } 
                                                  }  
                                        ORDER BY  DESC (?time) 
                                        LIMIT     1
                                     )  > 0
                                  )
                               ,  "Take Bus"
                               ,  (
                                        IF (
                                              (
                                                 (  SELECT    ?value 
                                                    WHERE
                                                              {
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:value              ?value           }
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  rdf:label                   "Availability"   }
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:isObservedValueOf  ?obsID           }
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observationResultTime   ?time            }
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsID       ssn:observedBy              ?id              }
                                                                 GRAPH meta: { ?id          rdf:label                   "MyBikeService"  } 
                                                              } 
                                                    ORDER BY  DESC (?time) 
                                                    LIMIT     1
                                                 )  > 0
                                              )
                                           ,  "Take Bike"
                                           ,  "Take Taxi"
                                           )
                                  )
                               )  AS  ?travelMethod
                         ) 
        FROM         data: 
        WHERE        { ?1  ?2  ?3 }
     }
```

Having spent a little time away from it, and re-reading what you said about your data in the comments above, I can refine this query further, which may also make it execute faster --

```
SELECT ?travelMethod 
   WHERE 
     { 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                         ( IF 
                               (
                                  (
                                     (  SELECT    ?value 
                                        WHERE     
                                                  {
                                                     GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:value              ?value
                                                                             ;  rdf:label                   "Availability"
                                                                             ;  ontology:isObservedValueOf  ?obsID
                                                                 . ?obsID       ssn:observationResultTime   ?time
                                                                             ;  ssn:observedBy              ?id
                                                                 }
                                                     GRAPH meta: { ?id          rdf:label                   "MyBusService"  } 
                                                  }  
                                        ORDER BY  DESC (?time) 
                                        LIMIT     1
                                     )  > 0
                                  )
                               ,  "Take Bus"
                               ,  (
                                        IF (
                                              (
                                                 (  SELECT    ?value 
                                                    WHERE
                                                              {
                                                                 GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID  ontology:value              ?value
                                                                                         ;  rdf:label                   "Availability"
                                                                                         ;  ontology:isObservedValueOf  ?obsID
                                                                             . ?obsID       ssn:observationResultTime   ?time
                                                                                         ;  ssn:observedBy              ?id
                                                                             }
                                                                 GRAPH meta: { ?id          rdf:label                   "MyBikeService"  } 
                                                              } 
                                                    ORDER BY  DESC (?time) 
                                                    LIMIT     1
                                                 )  > 0
                                              )
                                           ,  "Take Bike"
                                           ,  "Take Taxi"
                                           )
                                  )
                               )  AS  ?travelMethod
                         ) 
        FROM         data: 
        WHERE        { ?1  ?2  ?3 }
     }
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: While yours may be successfully executed by some endpoints, it's not valid SPARQL, so that success is a bit of a gamble.  Also, I detailed more of what's going on -- what I changed and why.  I hoped to make it clearer with my extra whitespace.  Trimming those spaces and line feeds, your query starts `SELECT ?isBusAvailable WHERE { SELECT DISTINCT IF ( ( SELECT ?value WHERE` while mine is `SELECT ?travelMethod WHERE { SELECT DISTINCT ( IF ( ( ( SELECT ?value WHERE` -- and the parentheses I added (one before the `IF` and one before the second `SELECT`) are required by SPARQL 1.1 syntax.

Comment: I tested this query and it works. Again the only difference from my answer is the wrapping the if statement into parantheses. Also, adding the semicolons and the dot makes the query not very intuitive a newbie in sparql. Can you explain in your answer why do you think this will run faster? Also, I assume that the semicolon is used to avoid repetion, but what it is the purpose of the dot before "?obsID" ?

Comment: I replaced 5 sentences with 2 — one with 2 predicates about `?obsID` and one with 3 predicates about `obsValueID`. In more detail — where you had 5 references to the `data:` graph, each a separate quad wrapped in `{ }`, I made these a single reference to the `data:` graph with 5 triples. This may speed things (depending on the processing engine) because the engine may load/process this graph once instead of 5 times. Within that, the semicolon is just syntactic sugar which decreases query string length (when the padding whitespace is removed).  The dot was implied by the `}` it replaced.

Comment: Also note that there was a second parenthetical wrapping I added -- the complete "test" expression in the `IF` construction gets wrapped in parens -- `IF ( ( test1 = test2 ) , "true" , "false" )`.  You had  `IF ( ( SELECT ?value … LIMIT 1 ) > 0 , "Take Bike" , "Take Taxi" )`.  I have `IF ( ( ( SELECT ?value … LIMIT 1 ) > 0 ) , "Take Bike" , "Take Taxi" )`.  I know these are hard to see; I hope my indentation and padding helps.

Answer (score 0):

The query in the false condition needs to respect the format of IF conditional statement from SPARQL since it returns a value. Remove the "SELECT DISTINCT"

```sql
SELECT ?isBusAvailable WHERE { 
  SELECT DISTINCT (IF(
        (
         SELECT ?value WHERE {
                GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID ontology:value ?value }
                GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID rdf:label "Availability" }
                GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID ontology:isObservedValueOf ?obsID}
                GRAPH data: { ?obsID ssn:observationResultTime ?time }
                GRAPH data: { ?obsID ssn:observedBy ?id }
                GRAPH meta: { ?id rdf:label "MyBusService" } 
        } ORDER BY DESC (?time) LIMIT 1) > 0,'Take Bus', (

                       IF (
                       (
                       SELECT ?value WHERE {
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID ontology:value ?value }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID rdf:label "Availability" }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsValueID ontology:isObservedValueOf ?obsID}
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsID ssn:observationResultTime ?time }
                            GRAPH data: { ?obsID ssn:observedBy ?id }
                            GRAPH meta: { ?id rdf:label "MyBikeService" } 
                       } ORDER BY DESC (?time) LIMIT 1
                       ) > 0, "Take Bike", "Take Taxi")
                       )) AS ?isBusAvailable) FROM data: WHERE { ?1 ?2 ?3 }}
```

**EDIT:** `select distinct if( ... )` isn't legal SPARQL, so the if statement needs to be wrapped into parentheses. The query becomes: `select distinct (if( ... ))`

Comment: I don't understand the notation you've put before this query... and further cannot tell whether this is meant as an answer to your original question, or as a followup.  If a followup, better to edit the question to include this information, hopefully expressed more clearly (and then to delete this answer).

Comment: This is my answer, and the query that worked. I used http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSSPARQL